# How can I handle a ajax request response in the Flux Architecture?

Tags: ajax, reactjs-flux

Looking at the [Flux Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html#content) I can't figure out how the code to a ajax update, and a ajax fetch would fit into the dispatcher, store, component architecture.

Can anyone provide a simple, dummy example, of how an entity of data would be fetched from the server AFTER page load, and how this entity would be pushed to the server at a later date. How would the "complete" or "error" status of request be translated and treated by the views/components? How would a store wait for the ajax request to wait? :-?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

you can also implement a fetch in the store in order to manage the information.

Here is an example (it is a concept, not actually working code):

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var Constants = require('constants');
var merge = require('react/lib/merge'); //This must be replaced for assign
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var Dispatcher = require('dispatcher');

var CHANGE_EVENT = "change";

var data = {};
var message = "";

function _fetch () {
  message = "Fetching data";
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Url',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data){
      message = "";
      MyStore.emitChange();
    },
    error: function(error){
      message = error;
      MyStore.emitChange();
    }
  });
};

function _post (myData) {
  //Make post
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Url',
    // post payload:
    data: JSON.stringify(myData),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data){
      message = "";
      MyStore.emitChange();
    },
    error: function(error){
      message = "update failed";
      MyStore.emitChange();
    }
  });
};

var MyStore = merge(EventEmitter.prototype, {
  emitChange: function () {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  },

  addChangeListener: function (callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },

  removeChangeListener: function (callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },

  getData: function (){
    if(!data){
      _fetch();
    }
    return data;
  },

  getMessage: function (){
    return message;
  },

  dispatcherIndex: Dispatcher.register( function(payload) {
    var action = payload.action; // this is our action from handleViewAction

    switch(action.actionType){
      case Constants.UPDATE:
        message = "updating...";
        _post(payload.action.data);
        break;
    }
    MyStore.emitChange();
    return true;
  })
});

module.exports = MyStore;
```

Then you need to subscribe your component to the store change events

```
var React = require('react');

var MyStore = require('my-store');

function getComments (){
  return {
    message: null,
    data: MyStore.getData()
  }
};

var AlbumComments = module.exports = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return getData();
  },
  componentWillMount: function(){
    MyStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    MyStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },
  _onChange: function(){
    var msg = MyStore.getMessage();
    if (!message){
      this.setState(getData());
    } else {
      this.setState({
        message: msg,
        data: null
      });
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    console.log('render');
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.message }
        {this.state.data.map(function(item){
          return <div>{ item }</div>
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but from this code it seems that the component is requesting data directly from the store, without the need of a dispatcher and a action payload. Since the dispatcher has a waitFor method, and some store might do async ops to update, this solution doesn't work. We either have sync stores all the time, or we have a different type of dispatcher.